# Using annotations to flow information from model building to migrations in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

For EF Core. Related [to this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7957#issuecomment-290514470) on the repo.

How do I "flow information" from the model building to the migrations stages in EF Core?

That issue was discussed among the authors who obviously fully understand the internals of EF Core, but I don't. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, flow your annotation from the model into the migration operations. Do this by overriding the provider-specific `IMigrationsAnnotationProvider` service.

```
class MyMigrationsAnnotationProvider : SqlServerMigrationsAnnotationProvider
{
    public override IEnumerable<IAnnotation> For(IProperty property)
        => base.For(property)
            .Concat(property.GetAnnotations().Where(a => a.Name == "MyAnnotation"));
}
```

Second, use the annotation in the provider-specific `IMigrationsSqlGenerator` service to generate DDL.

```
class MyMigrationsSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator
{
    protected override void Generate(
        AddColumnOperation operation,
        IModel model,
        MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
    {
        var myAnnotation = operation.FindAnnotation("MyAnnotation");
        if (myAnnotation != null)
        {
            // TODO: Add custom SQL using builder
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, configure your context to use your services.

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
   .ReplaceService<SqlServerMigrationsAnnotationProvider, MyMigrationsAnnotationProvider>()
   .ReplaceService<SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator, MyMigrationsSqlGenerator>();
```